# Dataframe becomes Nonetype after first loop

Tags: python, pandas

After the first for loop runs once contDF is set to a Nonetype object. Thus it runs into a problem since contDF[col] does not exist the second loop. At the end of the first loop contDF is correct. Some how it becomes none when the second loop starts.

```
def Lable_Controls_and_Exper(colum_name, list_values_to_determine_control, list_values_to_determine_exper):
contDF = copy.deepcopy(masterDF)

for col in colum_name:
    index = 0
    print(col+':')
    print(contDF)
    print(contDF[col])
    for element in contDF[col]:
        #print(index)
        #if list values match a row in a column then the row is excluded
        for value in list_values_to_determine_control:

            if(element == value 
                and contDF.loc[index,'control_or_experiment'] != 'exper'):
                contDF.loc[index,'control_or_experiment'] = 'control'

        for value in list_values_to_determine_exper:
            if(element == value):
                contDF.loc[ index, 'control_or_experiment' ] = 'exper'

        index = index + 1 
    print(contDF)
    print(contDF[col])
```

Here is the output.

> depression_bipolar_schizophrenia:
>                #SampleID age_years                              antibiotic_history  \
>       0  10317.000049761        52  I have not taken antibiotics in the past year.
>       1  10317.000040165        32  I have not taken antibiotics in the past year.
>       2  10317.000030322      43.0  I have not taken antibiotics in the past year.
>       3  10317.000028857      56.0  I have not taken antibiotics in the past year.
>       4  10317.000038189      39.0  I have not taken antibiotics in the past year.
>       5  10317.000001281      61.0  I have not taken antibiotics in the past year.
>       6  10317.000036487      46.0  I have not taken antibiotics in the past year.
>
> ```
>        bmi_cat depression_bipolar_schizophrenia  \
> 0   Overweight                      Unspecified   
> 1  Unspecified                      Unspecified   
> 2       Normal     I do not have this condition   
> 3   Overweight     I do not have this condition   
> 4   Overweight                      Unspecified   
> 5  Unspecified                      Unspecified   
> 6        Obese     I do not have this condition   
>
>   mental_illness_type_depression smoking_frequency control_or_experiment  
> 0                    Unspecified             Never                  none  
> 1                    Unspecified             Never                  none  
> 2                    Unspecified             Never                  none  
> 3                    Unspecified             Never                  none  
> 4                    Unspecified             Never                  none  
> 5                    Unspecified             Never                  none  
> 6                    Unspecified             Never                  none  
> 0                     Unspecified
> 1                     Unspecified
> 2    I do not have this condition
> 3    I do not have this condition
> 4                     Unspecified
> 5                     Unspecified
> 6    I do not have this condition
> Name: depression_bipolar_schizophrenia, dtype: object
>          #SampleID age_years                              antibiotic_history  \
> 0  10317.000049761        52  I have not taken antibiotics in the past year.   
> 1  10317.000040165        32  I have not taken antibiotics in the past year.   
> 2  10317.000030322      43.0  I have not taken antibiotics in the past year.   
> 3  10317.000028857      56.0  I have not taken antibiotics in the past year.   
> 4  10317.000038189      39.0  I have not taken antibiotics in the past year.   
> 5  10317.000001281      61.0  I have not taken antibiotics in the past year.   
> 6  10317.000036487      46.0  I have not taken antibiotics in the past year.   
>
>        bmi_cat depression_bipolar_schizophrenia  \
> 0   Overweight                      Unspecified   
> 1  Unspecified                      Unspecified   
> 2       Normal     I do not have this condition   
> 3   Overweight     I do not have this condition   
> 4   Overweight                      Unspecified   
> 5  Unspecified                      Unspecified   
> 6        Obese     I do not have this condition   
>
>   mental_illness_type_depression smoking_frequency control_or_experiment  
> 0                    Unspecified             Never               control  
> 1                    Unspecified             Never               control  
> 2                    Unspecified             Never               control  
> 3                    Unspecified             Never               control  
> 4                    Unspecified             Never               control  
> 5                    Unspecified             Never               control  
> 6                    Unspecified             Never               control  
> 0                     Unspecified
> 1                     Unspecified
> 2    I do not have this condition
> 3    I do not have this condition
> 4                     Unspecified
> 5                     Unspecified
> 6    I do not have this condition
> Name: depression_bipolar_schizophrenia, dtype: object
> mental_illness_type_depression:
> None
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-13-365067e6465a> in <module>()
>      11     col_data_control = user_input_controlDF[col_name].tolist()
>      12     col_data_exper = user_input_experimentDF[col_name].tolist()
> ---> 13     masterDF = Lable_Controls_and_Exper([col_name], col_data_control, col_data_exper)
>      14     while_count_two = while_count_two + 1
>      15 print("done")
>
> <ipython-input-12-3898e2174ad7> in Lable_Controls_and_Exper(colum_name, list_values_to_determine_control,
> ```
>
> list_values_to_determine_exper)
>             6         print(col+':')
>             7         print(contDF)
>       ----> 8         print(contDF[col])
>             9         for element in contDF[col]:
>            10             #print(index)
>
> ```
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
> ```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide an example of the dataframe that can be cut & pasted.  [See How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

While you didn’t include the relevant code in your code dump, it happened to show up in your traceback:

```
masterDF = Lable_Controls_and_Exper([col_name], col_data_control, col_data_exper)
```

Whatever this function returns, you assign that result to `masterDF`.

Since there’s no `return` statements anywhere in the function, it returns `None`, which means you assign that `None` to `masterDF`.

And notice that you’re passing `[col_name]`—a list of one element—to that first parameter. So the loop only happens once. The next time through the loop won’t be until the next time you call this function.

And the next time you call the function, when it deepcopies `masterDF`, it’s copying `None`.

Since it’s not clear what this code is trying to do, it’s hard to tell you how to fix it, but it’s almost certainly one of these two things:

1. Don’t assign the result of this function to `masterDF`, or
2. Change this function to return something useful that you want assigned to `masterDF`.